tomcat cannot startup with catalina error
New TomCat10 or 9 throws following error on startup.bat via catalina
Error: Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""Error: Could not find or load main class Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402-1\jre\lib\security\cacerts?

How to solve this problem?
bin\startup.bat throws error even after setting catalina_home

Looks like is something wrong with your environment variables.


Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.402-1\jre\lib\security\cacerts

You should find this string and escape it using quotes (the space in Program Files breaks the command)
